# xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)

Tags: xcode, macos, xcrun

I've upgraded OSX Lion to Mountain Lion and reinstalled the Command Line Tools (as the upgrade deleted them). From then xcrun does not work anymore. The xcode-select is set to /usr/bin, the binaries are in that directory too, but if I run xcrun with an argument (ex. xcrun gcc) it displays this:

```
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
```

I've tried setting the path again with xcode-select and reinstalled the CLT. Nothing helped.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Bump.  I've tried uninstalling the command line tools with the script provided in this article: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/ and I'm still having the same problems.  I reinstalled the command line tools using the separate download.  Still have the same problem.

Comment: FYI, I found this too: http://thomas.bindzus.me/2012/08/17/after-upgrading-to-mountain-lions-problems/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only fix is hack apparently.  I tried the script mentioned and it worked

[OSX 10.8 xcrun (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041525/osx-10-8-xcrun-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Just made a clean reinstall of my Mac. Mountain Lion, command-line tools, homebrew, rvm. And I came across this issue. The ``xcrun`` hack, though quite ugly, works well. Thanks a lot for pointing this out, I wouldn't have found the other discussion otherwise.

Answer (score 74):

I had the same problem. Originally I was doing the following for my xcode-switch:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

However what was really needed was:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

This fixed the problem for me.
Not sure if sudo is needed.

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to replace Xcode.app with Xcode_4.4.1.app because I renamed my Xcode.app file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for OP's situation (mine too) where the standalone Command Line Tools are installed in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: After struggling for days with this issue I found in this post my answer. Thanks a lot!. It should be marked as accepted.

Comment: This fixed an issue I was having with the TestFlight desktop app failing to build the IPA to upload, thanks!

Comment: If you are using Xcode5 preleases, you'll have to explcitly point to them, 

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode5-DP5.app/Contents/Developer/