# rails install: xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the tutorial at: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2#sec-install_ruby

When I do `sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.9` I get this error:

> ```
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing rails:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
>     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
> extconf.rb creating Makefile
>
> make xcrun cc -I.
> -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0
> -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0
> -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O3 -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c generator.c xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory) cc -arch i386 -arch
> x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o generator.bundle
> generator.o -L.
> -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc   clang: error: no such file or directory: 'generator.o' make: ***
> [generator.bundle] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
> Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
> ```

I've installed command line tools

I've set
sudo xcode-select -switch /usr/bin

which xcode-select
/usr/bin/xcode-select

which cc
/usr/bin/cc

any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: Did you try the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977648/xcrun-error-failed-to-exec-real-xcrun-no-such-file-or-directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the full XCode app to build C extensions to gems using the system Ruby.

If you don't want to install XCode, another alternative is to compile your own Ruby using [rvm](http://rvm.io/), [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build), or [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone using Xcode 5:

1. Install command line from Xcode's settings menu
2. use "mac port" to install ruby 1.8.7
3. retry "gem install cocopods"

This fixed my identical issue.