# Mac terminal returns "xcrun: error: unable to exec Xcode native xcrun (Exec format error)."

Tags: xcode, macos, git, github, terminal

Mac OS X V. 10.9.4 2.4 GHz 2 GB RAM

Im trying to use Git through my mac terminal and it keeps returning this error every time I submit a git command: "xcrun: error: unable to exec Xcode native xcrun (Exec format error).".

I already installed git and github in my mac. Im somehow new to programming I i don't really understand whats causing this error. Its getting very frustrating.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977648/xcrun-error-failed-to-exec-real-xcrun-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 22):

The following works for me:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

The GUI equivalent of this is to log into the machine, open Xcode, go to preferences, locations, and set the active command line tools version of xcode

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar `xcrun: error: unable to exec Xcode native xcrun (Not a directory).` on my mac which is managed by a central admin. I had to run my command with sudo.